# Sampling subsets of a given PDF with controllable sum and frequency

Tags: distributions, python, sampling, density-function, kernel-smoothing

I am working with a dataset with $n$ samples and $d$ features for each sample.

I would like to be able to sample "nice" subsets of this dataset with specific properties. Assume that this dataset follows a PDF (which I obtain using KDE in the scikit-learn Python library). For the purpose of discussion, I say this dataset has $m$ high-density regions that should be detected by the KDE.

I would like to do the following

- Sample a subset $A$ of the domain of the dataset where the subset is selected by only taking a subset of the $m$ high density areas. I should be able to control the percentage of the PDF that is selected. For example, if I say 50%, it should randomly select $\sim m / 2$ of the high-density regions. A subset can be a simple function $f$ which says if the sample $x$ is in the subset (True or False).
- Sample a subset $B$ of this dataset which is a superset of subset $A$, and similarly I should be able to control the percentage of the PDF that is selected.
- These subsets should be spatially "low-frequency" with respect to the domain of the dataset. As in the regions of the domain of the dataset that are within the subset should not change quickly if we spatially move a small amount within the domain. If this frequency is controllable, that would be great.

Uniform random sampling from the dataset would not achieve this obviously, since it would sample uniformly from the entire dataset. I had the intuition that KDE is perhaps needed, but I wasn't sure what to do after that.

If I divide the dataset into a grid, and select a subset of pixels, that could work, but as I increase the pixel size, the boundaries of the subset would not be smooth and would not be related to the actual density of the dataset, and might cut the dataset into unintuitive ways. There would also be no notion of clusters of pixels which is something that I want.

If I fit a GMM to the dataset and select a subset of gaussians that could also work, but I want some more generalized notion of picking a subset. For example, given a dataset with 2 gaussians, this subset sampling procedure should be able to pick say, the first gaussian and also spatially half of the second gaussian.

A possible idea is to randomly spatially place a few kernels (gassian, tophat, linear, etc.) on the PDF of the dataset such that a certain integral of the PDF is met. The bandwidth of these kernels would need to be within a certain range, so that we ensure that the low spatial frequency and smoothness goals are held. How to do this I am not sure.

Any ideas are appreciated.

For example, given a distribution such as:

[image]

And a percentage/sum/integral value like 70%, and a frequency number indicating "low-frequency" it should sample subsets like this:

[image]

and not like this:

[image]

Note that if we take the integral of the blue distribution in the yellow regions, we get 0.7, but in the last example, the subset is "high-frequency". This frequency value should be controllable, ideally per dimension/feature.